# Scala: what's def actually do?

Tags: scala

In Scala, **def** defined a function, But i don't understand the below code. 
Ex.

```
def v = 10
```

what's v defination? v is a variable or a function or anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's a function that always returns 10. in Java, the equivalent would be

```
public int v() { return 10; }
```

this might seem pointless, but the difference is real, and sometimes importantly useful. for example, suppose i define a trait like this:

```
trait Wrench {
  val size = 14 //millimeters, the default, most common size
}
```

if i need different size wrench, i can refine the trait

```
val bigWrench = new Wrench {
  override val size = 21
}
```

but what if I want an adjustable wrench?

```
// mutable! not thread safe!
class AdjustableWrench extends Wrench {
  var adjustment = 0

  override val size = 14 + (3 * adjustment) // oops!

  def adjust( turns : Int ) : Unit = {
    adjustment += turns
  }
}
```

this won't work! `size` will always be 14!

if I had defined my trait originally as

```
trait Wrench {
  def size = 14 //millimeters, the default, most common size
}
```

i'd be able to define `bigWrench` exactly as I did above, because a `val` can override a `def`. but now i can write a functional adjustable wrench too:

```
// mutable! not thread safe!
class AdjustableWrench extends Wrench {
  var adjustment = 0

  override def size = 14 + (3 * adjustment) // this works

  def adjust( turns : Int ) : Unit = {
    adjustment += turns
  }
}
```

by originally defining `size` as a `def`, rather than a `val` in the base trait, even though it looked dumb, I preserved the flexibility to override with `def` or `val`. it's quite common to define a base trait with very simple defaults, but where implementations might want to do something more complicated. so statements like

```
def v = 10
```

are not at all rare.

to get your head around the difference a bit more, compare these two:

```
def vDef = {
  println("vDef")
  10
}
```

and

```
val vVal = {
  println("vVal")
  10
}
```

both `vDef` and `vVal` will evaluate to 10 whenever you access them. but each time you access vDef, you will see the side effect, a print out of `vDef`. no matter how any times you access `vVal`, you will see `vVal` printed out just once.

Answer (score 1):

`v` is a function that always returns 10.
Equivalent code in Java would be:

```
public int v() {
  return 10;
}
```

Also see [2nd chapter](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/first-steps-in-scala.html#step3) from "Programming in Scala" book.